# Find age of John

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

Ten years before Alice's age is 4 times John's age. Ten years later, Alice's age is 2 times John's age. How old is John?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

John is

> 20. Ten years earlier, John was 10 and Alice was 40. Ten years from now, Alice will be 60 and John will be 30.

Answer (score 11):

John is

> 20

Equations

> Let age of Alice now be *a* and age of John now be *j*. Therefore 10 years ago, 
>  $$a-10=4(j-10)$$

and

> After 10 years 
>  $$a+10=2(j+10)$$

Solving two equations we get

> j = 20 and a = 50. So today age of John is 20 years.

This proves that this is a $6^{th}$ grade math problem.